# c# csvhelper how to parse string to datetime object

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following csv

```
Date,Stage,Count,Time,Index
20151231,4,3,9:45:3991,1527.23510
20150903,4,613,12:18:0483,1605.56522
```

and the following code

```
public List<DailyData> ReadDailyData(string dataFolder)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(dataFolder))
    {
        var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
        return reader.GetRecords<DailyData>().ToList();
    }
}

public class DailyData
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Stage { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

CsvHelper is working fine when converting to string
However when I try to parse to DateTime I get Exception

i.e

```
public class DailyData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // should be Date obj
    public string Stage { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; } // should be Time obj
    public string Index { get; set; }
}
```

I get: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: What line of code is it failing on and what is the exception?  Two important things you left out of your post.

Comment: What exception? What is the type, the stack trace, the message, the InnerException? We can't really guess those details. If I had to take a guess its probably a FormatException, you are asking the datetime and Time (what is Time, maybe TimeSpan?)  type to guess the format of the string.

Comment: Have you tried to use the CSVHelper mapping?

Comment: The help page for the API has a section called [Type Converter Options](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). This is probably what you need, to instruct the CsvHelper on how to convert your strings to the expected types.

Comment: If you look at your data, I'm sure you will understand why. `9:45:3991` is not a valid DateTime.

Comment: Thanks all (and Rick), this is the csv, how can I format it?

Comment: As the others have suggested you can make the "Time"  property a `TimeSpan` field and then use CSV Mapping to convert your string to Timespan.  Your other option is to make the Time property a string, then you don't have to do anything to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map class to give the format of the date and time that you want.

```cs
class DailyData
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // should be Date obj
    public string Stage { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; } // should be Time obj
    public string Index { get; set; }
}

public class DailyDataMap: ClassMap<DailyData> {
        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyyMMdd");
        Map(m => m.Stage);
        Map(m => m.Count);
        Map(m => m.Time).TypeConverterOption.Format("H:mm:ffff");
        Map(m => m.Index);
}
```